# DMGR Console is very slow, what could be the possible reasons?

Tags: websphere

Dmgr console of development environment is very slow, we checked from all aspects but unable to find the exact reason.

Dev WebSphere is running in AIX server which has 20 GB of RAM initially, we even increased the RAM to 8 GB but still facing the slowness with 28 GB of RAM.

And we have 10 different JVMs running in 10 differnt clusters in Dev which shares the RAM like below

JVM1 1 Gb JVM2 2 JVM3 2 JVM4 1 JVM5 2 JVM1 1 JVM1 1 JVM1 1 JVM1 2 JVM1 2 DMGR 2 Nodeagent 256 MB

So total of 17.6 GB (of 28) is used for RAM, but still we facing slowness in DMGR while

1.) Navigating
2.) Giving Node Synchronisation
3.) Starting of the DMGR
4.) And we have 24 applications running in Dev with 4 to 5 applications has 330 MB of size deployed in some JVMs having 2GB of RAM (will it this could be one of the reason?)

What could be the possible reason for this dmgr slowness? Can anyone tell me

Comment: What version and fix level of WebSphere? And when you say you increased the RAM to 8GB, what do you mean? You increased the Dmgr process' maximum heap to 8GB?

Comment: There could be several causes.  If the apps or servers are stopped, does the problem go away? (suggests overloaded servers or communication problems with them, turn on verbose gc to check).  If cell security is disabled, does the problem go away? (suggests a slow ldap server or comm problems).  If this is all one node, the node agent RAM seems low.  Is response better with an administrative ID? (suggests fine grained admin security setup problems.)

Answer (score 1):

A low max JVM heap size on the dmgr JVM can cause the interactive bits of the console to act mysteriously slow.

You can change the heap size pretty easily:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21329319

1. In the navigation panel, click System Administration > Deployment
   Manager > Process definition.
2. Under Additional Properties, click
   Java Virtual Machine. Type 1024 in the Maximum Heap Size field.
3. Save
   the changes to the master repository.
4. Restart all servers, node
   agents, and the deployment manager.

Answer (score 0):

We removed hosts from the virtual hosts that are no longer used/not on the network anymore. This seems to have helped.